# Would like to make a healpix log density all-sky map with healpy

Tags: astronomy, astropy, healpy

I have a set of large, >10M object, files with R.A.s and Declinations. I'd like to make log density all-sky maps of these, using, I presume healpix/healpy. My current code looks like this:

```
 m = hp.ang2pix(512, ra, dec, lonlat=True)
 NSIDE = 512
 np.arange(hp.nside2npix(NSIDE))
 hp.visufunc.mollview(m)
```

and I get the error:

```
 ValueError: Wrong pixel number (it is not 12*nside**2)
```

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks, 
Nic

Comment: Healpix maps require a fixed number of points, as given by the error: 12 * n^2, with n an integer number (normally, these points are also spread evenly across the sky). You don't have the right amount of points. Note that ` np.arange(hp.nside2npix(NSIDE))` would give you the number of points required (or rather, the indices), but now, it's just an empty function call, since you don't assign it to anything.

Answer (score 2):

Here m is an array of length ra, (and dec). You first need to convert m into an healpix map, [or array] of length 12*NSIDE^2.

To do this, you can use numpy.bincount [very fast, and gives you the number of objects in each pixel], or scipy.stats.binned_statistic, [very slow, but allows you to calculate any 'statistic' like np.std etc you like, of the data the sits in each pixel]

```
def gen_fast_map(ip_, nside=512):
    npixel  = hp.nside2npix(nside)
    map_ = np.bincount(ip_,minlength=npixel)
    return map_

map = gen_fast_map(m)
hp.visufunc.mollview(map)
```